# Erro com thread: Controle acessado de um thread que não é aquele no qual foi criado

Tags: c#, thread

Estou com um bloco de código e preciso que ele execute a cada `x` segundos, sendo assim usei a classe `Timer` e passei como parâmetro o método que eu quero executar, e os tempos, início e intervalo. Porém o código está estourando uma exceção, acusando `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Operação entre threads inválida: controle 'lblTotalEncontrados' acessado de um thread que não é aquele no qual foi criado.'` esse `controle` **lblTotalEncontrados** é um atributo do meu formulário, gostaria de saber como faço para a thread da class `Timer` conseguir alterar e manipular todos os atributos do meu formulário.

**Segue as principais parte do código:**

```
//Usando a classe Timer Passando a função e os tempos como parâmetro
System.Threading.Timer t = new System.Threading.Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 120000);

//Método invocado passado para a classe Timer
public void TimerCallback(Object o)
        {
            //Todas partes desse bloco de código manipula atributos do formulário que está em outra thread

            this.txtQuantidadeHistorico.Text = this.topHistoricoUser.ToString();
            this.txtQuantidadeHistorico.Refresh();
            ResetLabelTransferidos_Encontrados();            
            SetTotalFilesInDirectory(directoryInfoSource);
            Process(directoryInfoSource);
            UpdateTxtUltimos();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Isso acontece pois seu evento está rodando em uma `thread` e seus controles foram criados na `thread` principal. Infelizmente você não pode acessa-los diretamente em sua thread.

A forma mais correta de resolver este problema, é manter a parte do código que não interage com os componentes do `form` em um método e todo o resto em outro.

Abaixo um exemplo de como você pode construir um método para fazer essa operação:

```
public delegate void TimerCallbackDelegate(object o);

//Método invocado passado para a classe Timer
public void TimerCallback(Object o)
{
    //Verifica se é necessário invocar esse método na thread principal para interagir com os controles
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        //Invoca este próprio método
        Invoke((TimerCallbackDelegate)TimerCallback, o);
    }
    else
    {
        //Aqui seu código estará rodando na thread principal e será possível interagir com os componentes
        txtQuantidadeHistorico.Text = "teste";
    }
}
```